# Error with Struct in C++

Tags: c++, header, struct

I'm having a problem with a struct when trying to do this in C++ (visual studio):

memoria.cpp

```
  struct readMem {
    UINT32 startAdress;
    UINT32 endAdress;
    UINT8(*memoryHandler) (UINT32);
    void *pUserData;
};

struct writeMem {
    UINT32 startAdress;
    UINT32 endAdress;
    void (*memoryHandler) (UINT32, UINT8);
    void *pUserData;
};



 void memoria::writeRAMBankEnable(UINT32 a, UINT8 b) {
}

void memoria::writeROMBankSelect(UINT32 a, UINT8 b) {
}

void memoria::writeRAMROMModeSelect(UINT32 a, UINT8 b) {
}

void memoria::writeVRAM(UINT32 a, UINT8 b) {
}

void memoria::writeSRAM(UINT32 a, UINT8 b) {
}

void memoria::writeRAM(UINT32 a, UINT8 b) {
}

void memoria::writeERAM(UINT32 a, UINT8 b) {
}

void memoria::writeSprite(UINT32 a, UINT8 b) {
}

void memoria::writeIOM(UINT32 a, UINT8 b) {
}

void memoria::writeHRAM(UINT32 a, UINT8 b) {
}


struct writeMem implWriteMem[] = {
    { 0x0000, 0x1FFF, writeRAMBankEnable, NULL},
    { 0x4000, 0x5FFF, writeROMBankSelect, NULL},
    { 0x6000, 0x7FFF, writeRAMROMModeSelect, NULL},
    { 0x8000, 0x9FFF, writeVRAM, NULL},
    { 0xA000, 0xBFFF, writeSRAM, NULL},
    { 0xC000, 0xDFFF, writeRAM, NULL},
    { 0xE000, 0xFDFF, writeERAM, NULL},
    { 0xFE00, 0xFE9F, writeSprite, NULL},
    { 0xFF00, 0xFF7F, writeIOM, NULL},
    { 0xFF80, 0xFFFF, writeHRAM, NULL},
    { (UINT32) - 1, (UINT32) - 1, NULL, NULL}
};

    memoria.h    

        #pragma once

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "defs.h"

ref class memoria
{
public:
    memoria(void);

private:
    FILE *file;
    UINT8 *mem;
public:

    void writeRAMBankEnable(UINT32, UINT8);

    void writeROMBankSelect(UINT32, UINT8);

    void writeRAMROMModeSelect(UINT32, UINT8);

    void writeVRAM(UINT32, UINT8);

    void writeSRAM(UINT32, UINT8);

    void writeRAM(UINT32, UINT8);

    void writeERAM(UINT32, UINT8);

    void writeSprite(UINT32, UINT8);

    void writeIOM(UINT32, UINT8);

    void writeHRAM(UINT32, UINT8);

    UINT8 readRAMBankEnable(UINT32);

    UINT8 readROMBankSelect(UINT32);

    UINT8 readRAMROMModeSelect(UINT32);

    UINT8 readVRAM(UINT32);

    UINT8 readSRAM(UINT32);

    UINT8 readRAM(UINT32);

    UINT8 readERAM(UINT32);

    UINT8 readSprite(UINT32);

    UINT8 readIOM(UINT32);

    UINT8 readHRAM(UINT32);


    void Meminitialize();
    void MemcleanUp();

    void writeByte(UINT32, UINT8);
    UINT8 readByte(UINT32);

    void writeWord(UINT32, UINT16);
    UINT16 readWord(UINT32);
};
```

Visual studio c++ gives me this errors:

1>memoria.cpp(75): error C2065: 'writeRAMBankEnable' : undeclared identifier

1>memoria.cpp(76): error C2065: 'writeROMBankSelect' : undeclared identifier

1>memoria.cpp(77): error C2065: 'writeRAMROMModeSelect' : undeclared identifier

1>memoria.cpp(78): error C2065: 'writeVRAM' : undeclared identifier

1>memoria.cpp(79): error C2065: 'writeSRAM' : undeclared identifier

1>memoria.cpp(80): error C2065: 'writeRAM' : undeclared identifier

1>memoria.cpp(81): error C2065: 'writeERAM' : undeclared identifier

1>memoria.cpp(82): error C2065: 'writeSprite' : undeclared identifier

1>memoria.cpp(83): error C2065: 'writeIOM' : undeclared identifier

1>memoria.cpp(84): error C2065: 'writeHRAM' : undeclared identifier

1>memoria.cpp(169): error C2065: 'implReadMem' : undeclared identifier

1>memoria.cpp(179): error C2065: 'implReadMem' : undeclared identifier

For the record, I have declared all the functions in my memoria.h, all but the structs and the implWriteMem[], of course.
Anyway, how can I solve that?

P.S. It worked quite well in pure C.

Thanks !

Comment: provide header, impossible to tell what is happening

Comment: Pure C doesn't have namespaces. How did this work?

Comment: are you trying to create a DIY member functions?  Oh me god!!!!

Comment: @Anycorn: Not just member functions, but polymorphic (virtual) member functions.  So virtual functions and class inheritance would appear to be the better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{ 0x0000, 0x1FFF, writeRAMBankEnable, NULL},
```

Did you perhaps mean

```
{ 0x0000, 0x1FFF, &memoria::writeRAMBankEnable, NULL},
```

You have to include the class name when referring to a member, except within the class.  And when making a pointer to a member function, you always need the class name.

The best solution is to use the polymorphism features built into the language:

```
ref struct MemoryRegion abstract
{
     virtual uint8_t Read( uint32_t address ) = 0;
     virtual void Write( uint32_t address, uint8_t value ) = 0;
     const uint32_t start_address, end_address;
protected:
     MemoryRegion( uint32_t start, uint32_t end ) : start_address(start), end_address(end) {}
};

ref struct SRAM : MemoryRegion
{
     SRAM( uint32_t start, uint32_t end ) : MemoryRegion(start, end) {}
     virtual uint8_t Read(uint32_t address);
     virtual void Write(uint32_t address, uint8_t value);
};

ref struct RAM : MemoryRegion
{
     RAM( uint32_t start, uint32_t end ) : MemoryRegion(start, end) {}
     virtual uint8_t Read(uint32_t address);
     virtual void Write(uint32_t address, uint8_t value);
};

ref struct VRAM : MemoryRegion
{
     VRAM( uint32_t start, uint32_t end ) : MemoryRegion(start, end) {}
     virtual uint8_t Read(uint32_t address);
     virtual void Write(uint32_t address, uint8_t value);
};
```

and so on.  Then you can make an array of handles to the base type, and fill in all kinds of behavior-specific classes:

```
array<MemoryRegion^>^ memories = gcnew array<MemoryRegion^>(10);
memories[0] = gcnew SRAM(0xA000, 0xBFFF);
// ...
```

Comment: lets hope those member functions are static too.

Comment: @Anycorn: Yes, the struct does appear to store a normal function pointer, not a pointer-to-nonstatic-member type.

Comment: I think OP used a hack to recreate some OOP using C.  He probably shouldn't do that in C++ given that member functions are already present in the lang.

Comment: @BenVoigt I tried that but now I get this error:1>memoria.cpp(73): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void (__clrcall memoria::* )(unsigned int,unsigned char)' to 'void (__clrcall *)(unsigned int,unsigned char)' There is no context in which this conversion is possible

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari: That's what Anycom was talking about.  Non-static member functions aren't compatible with normal functions.  And why didn't you tell us you were using C++/CLI and compiling to .NET?

Comment: @BenVoigt I did tell I'm using C++/CLI (visual C++). Anyway, I posted the header too. How can I make it work ? Thanks for the help !

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari: Most users of Visual C++ are not using the `/clr` compiler switch.  You have to tell people you're using C++/CLI.  Anyway, I've added to my answer, this should get you started again.

Comment: @BenVoigt But with the code you've provided me, I'll have to write a Read and Write function to every single case (SRAM, VRAM, ROM etc...) right ? I didn't want to do that... Anyway I'm kinda confuse with some things: 1st-> When implementing the code above, I had to add the override keyword to it, or it wouldn't work. 2nd-> When creating the array, I got a few errors, like this one: error C3145: 'memories' : global or static variable may not have managed type 'cli::array<Type> ^'. 3rd-> Do this functions replace my old ones, the writeBankEnable, WriteROM etc.. ? Thanks !

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari: From your question, it looked like you wanted separate functions for each memory type.  All I did was to move those functions into a class.  Yes, `override` makes sense.  And you may need to put the `memories` array inside another `ref class`, possibly as a static member.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thats correct, I do, but I need one generic, to call each separately. But I think this issue I can handle. I need to create a ref class to use the array ? I already have the class (memoria). Can't I just create a method or use it in the constructor ? Thanks ! I'm kinda new to this ref keyword, I have never used it.

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari: ok, I'm confused.  Do you want portable standard-compliant C++ code, or C++/CLI code that runs in .NET and plays well with C#?  If the former, then get rid of `ref` everywhere, change `array<MemoryRegion>` to `vector<MemoryRegion*>`.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sorry for the mess. Well, let me explain. I have 2 separete codes. I'm developing an gbc emulator in C but now I need an interface (GUI) for a debbuger (listBoxes, Buttons etc), so I'm using Visual C++ to make this GUI. Is there an easy way to integrate them both using standard C++ or I really need to use this C++/CLI crap ? Or even further, is there another GUI programming IDE as easy as Visual to work with, so I can easily "join" this two different piece of code ? Thanks again !

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari: There's already a lot of questions about GUI in C++.    But you definitely can use standard C++ alongside C++/CLI.  Use `#pragma mangaged(push, off)` and `#pragma managed(pop)` in the header files for the standard C++ parts, and turn off the `/clr` compiler option for the corresponding implementation files.  Or go with 100% standard C++ for the GUI and everything, using wxWidgets or Qt or something.  Again, just search for `[c++] GUI` and you'll find plenty of answers already on SO.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll give a try on QT. Thanks for all the support guys, especially BenVoigt ! If I need anything, I'll post here !